# Which preloader is preferred - image, css or javascript based?

Tags: javascript, image, css

We do have 3 way to run preloader:

1. Animated gif/png
2. Javascript
3. CSS3

Which technique is preferred? which one is cheaper with performance and which one is more suitable for mobile devices, old and new?

Thank you.

Comment: CSS! then an image. js is just heavy in terms of data required..BUT you can mix SVG or Canvas with CSS3 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best one to use for mobile devices is CSS3.

1. A lot less data, smaller image download size(users pay for mobile downloads).
2. Far smoother rendering experience.
3. Use media queries for resolution support. Much faster and easier than JavaScript.
4. Far easier to implement cross browser than a JavaScript alternative, especially in mobile.
5. Widely used, very easy to implement.
6. A lot of tools available to test your app.(Mozilla responsive design, etc..)